# schema or reference for maven-metadata.xml in maven 3 (specifically for <latest/>, <release/>)?

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, maven-metadata

I see Nexus OSS repo manager (re)generating the following maven-metadata.xml and cannot find any info on what do the following properties mean (or where can i find reference to maven-metata.xml - similar to [pom.xml](http://maventest.apache.org/pom.html))

- latest - not latest by version or lastUpdated timestamp in our case. Nexus FAQ [says](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464638-Why-are-the-latest-and-release-tags-in-maven-metadata-xml-not-being-updated-after-deploying-artifacts-) this only applies to plugin artifacts. Is that really so? Is it benign or harmful when present in for non-plugin artifacts?
- release - what is the significance of this property? When used for SNAPSHOT artifacts?

Artifact's maven-metadata.xml - as re-generated by Nexus:

```
<metadata>
  <groupId>com.castanealabs</groupId>
  <artifactId>castanealabs-config</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <latest>10-SNAPSHOT</latest>
    <release></release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>7-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>8-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>10-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <version>11-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20120321194127</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some references about the `maven-metadata.xml` file. In that case simple Google would have helped.

1. http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html
2. http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-repository-metadata/index.html
3. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3125